# Корректировка перевода норм поведения - "тех участников, чьё поведение непременно вредно"

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, нормы-поведения

Оригинал (по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/conduct):

> For very rare cases, moderators will expel people **who display a pattern of harmful destructive behavior toward our community.**

Текущий перевод (по ссылке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct):

> В очень редких случаях модераторы изгоняют из сообщества тех участников, чьё поведение **непременно** вредно.

Слово непременно кажется неподходящим ни буквально, ни по смыслу. Предлагаю исправить перевод на более корректный вариант:

> В очень редких случаях модераторы изгоняют из сообщества тех участников, чьё поведение носит целенаправленный деструктивный характер по отношению к сообществу.

Comment: Изгоняют... Звучит прям как экскоммуникация или анафема :D

Comment: @Suvitruf язык оригинала тоже пестрит заумными словами. ИМХО ему следовало бы быть более Simple English.

Comment: Вот тут скрин с причинами удаления у модераторов: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313749

Answer (score -1):

В текущем виде ваш вариант выглядит стилистически неудачным.

Например, формулировку можно исправить так:

> В очень редких случаях модераторы изгоняют из сообщества тех участников, чьё поведение исключительно вредно.

Из словаря:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Согласен, давайте искать лучший вариант вместе! Мне кажется стоит попробовать сохранить дух оригинала в плане того, что баним тех "в чьем поведении прослеживается паттерн (в смысле цель) нанесения вреда сообществу", а не просто "сильно навредил".

Comment: "Исключительно" подразумевает, что все (или почти все) сообщения дестркуктивны, тогда как в оригинале говорится о "шаблонах" поведения, которые "негативно влияют на сообщество". Т.е. всего 10% сообщений может быть деструктивны, но под шаблон подпадает такое поведение.

Comment: @Kromster отличное предложение («...Искать лучши вариант вместе!»)! Как вам такое: «...Тех участников, чья цель — вносить разлад в сообщество»?

Comment: @Aer я неуверен, может быть обсуждение стоит вести в чате - пожалуйста подскажите, как лучше/правильнее. "Разлад" наверно не совсем подходит, т.к. это конкретизация лишь одной из категорий наносимого вреда сообществу, а может быть и массовая накрутка голосов, манипулирование атмосферой (без разлада), и т.п.

Comment: "негативные действия" не подойдёт?

Comment: Поменял свой вариант на "целенаправленный деструктивный характер", это вроде бы ближе к паттерну и к духу причины изгнания после получения предупреждения и временного бана.

Comment: @Kromster вот что еще пришло в голову: «Тех, кто систематически нарушает правила поведения». По-моему, ок, да еще и все пункты правил сразу подразумевает )

Comment: @Suvitruf отрицательный еще куда не шло, но ведь отрицательный — это не просто плохой, а именно вызывающий порицание...

Comment: @Aer сообщества?

Comment: @Suvitruf многие сейчас порицают сами правила, так что едва ли сообщество одобрит удаление учетки за какой-нибудь систематический сарказм.

Comment: «Тех, кто систематически нарушает правила поведения» имхо не совпадает с духом англ. формулировки, которая направлена именно на злостных деструкторов "террористов/итп", а не тех, кто систематически "переходит дорогу не по зебре"

Comment: @Aer "систематически нарушает правила поведения" неплохо, вот только я могу нарушать правила, скажем, матом или неуместной иронией. Я бы не назвал это "деструктивными действиями", это нарушение правил поведения. Т.е. этот вариант слишком мягок относительно оригинала.

Comment: Пойдемте в чат: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22474/