# Пара предложений/правок по "Code of Conduct" в справке

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, нормы-поведения

Английский документ: https://stackoverflow.com/help/conduct
Русский документ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/conduct

1.

> join us in building a community where all people **feel welcome** and can participate, regardless of expertise or identity.

У нас:

> мы призываем вас принять участие в создании сообщества, где каждый чувствует себя **комфортно** и может быть полноценным участником, несмотря на специальные навыки и личностные качества.

**Feel welcome** это, скорее, "уютно", а не комфортно.

> join us in building a community

Никто никого не призывает, **join us** - это **приглашает**.

> regardless of expertise or identity

**regardless** - это, всё же, не **несмотря на**, а, скорее, **независимо от**. **expertise** - это **опыт**, а не **спец. навыки**. **identity** как **личностные качества** звучит как канцелярский текст, можно просто заменить на **характер**.

Т.е, всё предложение будет:

> Вне зависимости от того, хотите ли вы задать вопрос или поделиться своими знаниями, мы приглашаем вас принять участие в создании сообщества, где каждый чувствует себя уютно и может быть полноценным участником, независимо от его опыта и характера.

2.

> including our team, moderators, and anyone posting to Q&A sites or
>   chat rooms.

У нас:

> Мы обязуемся обеспечивать соблюдение и улучшение этих правил. Их
>   действие распространяется на всех участников сайта «Stack Overflow на
>   русском», а также других сообществ сети Stack Exchange, включая нашу
>   команду, модераторов и любого, кто оставляет сообщения в чатах.

Часть про **Q&A sites** вообще потеряли.

Предлагаю:

> Мы обязуемся обеспечивать соблюдение и улучшение этих правил. Их
>   действие распространяется на всех участников сайта «Stack Overflow на
>   русском», а также других сообществ сети Stack Exchange, включая нашу
>   команду, модераторов и любого, кто оставляет сообщения на сайтах
>   вопросов-ответов и в чатах.

3.

> If you’re here to get help, **make it as easy as possible for others to
>   help you**.

У нас:

> Если вы пришли за помощью, не препятствуйте желающим вам помочь.

В оригинале вообще речь о том, что помощь зависит от того, насколько хорошо будет задан вопрос.

Предлагаю что-нибудь такое:

> Если вы пришли за помощью, упростите работу желающим вам помочь.

4.

> Learning how to participate in our community **can** be hard

Может лучше так?

> Изучение норм и принципов нашего сообщества может быть нелёгкой
>   задачей. Если вы заметили, что кто-то испытывает трудности или
>   нуждается в любой другой помощи, помогите ему.

5.

> **If you** bothered to read my question, **you’d** know **it’s not** a duplicate

У нас:

> Если вы не утрудили себя прочитать мой вопрос, это не значит, что он
>   дубликат

Всё наизнанку. Должно быть:

> Если бы вы потрудились прочитать мой вопрос, вы бы знали, что это не дубликат

6.

> I came to get help, not to get my question edited

Часть про помощь выкинули совсем.

7.

> This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar
>   language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks,
>   patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of
>   discussion.

Это:

> Включает в себя(но не ограничивается): травлю, шантаж, нецензурную лексику, прямые и завуалированные угрозы, высказывания сексуального характера, неприличное и бестактное поведение, а также постоянное неконструктивное встревание в дискуссии — однако список не ограничен лишь этими явлениями.

8.

> Every person contributes to building a kind, respectful community

У нас:

> Каждый участник способен поддерживать дружелюбную атмосферу и взаимное
>   уважение в сообществе

Тут не предположение, а утверждение. Предлагаю заменить на:

> Каждый участник вносит свой вклад в создание доброжелательного,
>   основанного на взаимном уважении, сообщества.

9.

> We’ll respond as quickly as we **can**

Акцент на том, что модераторы занятые, даже если бы они хотели отвечать моментально, не всегда это возможно.

> Мы постараемся ответить как только сможем.

10.

> may face repercussions deemed appropriate

Ни слова про **заслуженное наказание** как у нас. Тут про последствия речь. Не всегда рассмотрение влечёт за собой наказание.

11.

> Account Suspension 
>   For repetitive misconduct or behavior containing
>   harassment, bigotry, or abuse, moderators will impose a temporary
>   suspension (one day or more, depending on the violation).

У нас:

> При повторных нарушениях или неприемлемом поведении модераторы
>   блокируют доступ к учётной записи виновника на некоторое время (один
>   день или больше — в зависимости от серьёзности ситуации).

Никто не будет блочить аккаунт за **неприемлемое поведение**, как написано у нас. В оригинале чёткий список нарушений дан.

12.

> For very rare cases, moderators will **expel** people who display a
>   pattern of harmful destructive behavior toward our community.

У нас:

> В очень редких случаях модераторы изгоняют из сообщества тех
>   участников, чьё поведение непременно вредно.

Мы ту не демоны, не надо нас изгонять. **expel** - это, скорее, **исключает**.

13.

> pattern of harmful destructive behavior toward our community

Про это отдельный тред есть:
[Корректировка перевода норм поведения - "тех участников, чьё поведение непременно вредно"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7671/15479)

14.

> We created this Code of Conduct because it reinforces the respect that
>   we, as a community, expect from one another

У нас:

> Мы создали эти правила, чтобы описать отношение, которого ждут друг от
>   друга участники нашего сообщества. Более того, они указывают на то,
>   чего мы, развиваясь, должны держаться.

Тут речь не про отдельных участников, а про **нас** как о **сообществе**. Мол мы как сообщество ожидаем.

Если это хоть как-то поможет улучшить страницу, то значит не зря писал.

Comment: Вы могли бы добавить соответствующие русские фразы целиком? Без контекста, неясно насколько предлагаемый вариант лучше/хуже.

Comment: @Kromster я просто не знал, как лучше будет в некоторых случаях. Просто назвал проблемные места на мой взгляд. Да и час ночи был (: Но подумаю над вариантами.